# What equipment can I use to prevent clothes rustle from a digital voice recorder?

Tags: voice, digital, recorder

I have a digital voice recorder (Olympus WS852) and I often put the recorder into my shirt pocket as I move around while having a conversation. I would like to reduce the clothes rustle as much as possible without post-processing.

I have come across products like the URSA foamies for external mics, and I don't understand the mechanics of how clothes rustle is made to be able to decide if a foamie 'sock' over my DVR mics would help.

What macgyver solutions have people used to successfully reduce clothes rustle?

Answer (score 1):

The trick to removing clothing rustle is to prevent the mic and the clothes from rubbing. Sounds simple, but it really isn't. There's two ways to approach this...

1. Stop the mic from achieving contact with clothing
2. Use a lavalier mic.

With a pocket recorder, even point 1. may be tricky due to the fact that you can get induced rustle through the device itself. The most reliable way to do this would be to use a lavalier and then use standard techniques for preventing lavalier rustle.

Comment: Would a silicone casing help or does it still transmit enough sound (or cause its own sound)?